# How to plot several plots with same legend ggplot2, R

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, legend

I just came into a problem while making several maps in R, the problem I came to is that I want to plot several maps and some geom_points in those maps, each map will have some points with different values and so the legend with the scales (size and color) will change between maps. All I want is to have exactly the same legend, representing the same values (for both color and size). I've tried with breaks etc but my data is continuous, so I didn't find any way to fix it.

EDIT:Simple example

Will try to explain with simple example by myself. Imagine I have these two arrays to be plotted into different coordinates for 2 different days:

```
 c<-(1,2,3,2,1)
 c<-(1,9,2,1,2)
```

What I want is to set the legend of the plot to be always representing the range 1-9 as values of the geom_points, no matter the specific values of the given day, in a way that no matter the values, the legend will be always the same and if I try to set some slides, the scale will not change

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: It is a bit hard to set an example since the dataset is pretty huge (~50 records a day during 1 year). Will try to explain with simple example by myself

Imagine I have these two arrays to be plotted into different coordinates for 2 different days:
    c<-(1,2,3,2,1) 
    c<-(1,9,2,1,2)

What I want is to set the legend of the plot to be always representing the range 1-9, no matter the specific values of the given day, in a way that no matter the values, the legend will be always the same and if I try to set some slides, the scale will not change.

Comment: Read  [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)